# Login PHP, me crea el objeto pero, pero me siguen apareciendo los inputs

Tags: php, login

Buenas noches compañeros, llevo 1 hora intentado averiguar el error por mi parte, pero me es imposible. (Soy novato 100%).

Estoy creando una tienda MVC con PHP7.
La creación de usuario me funciona perfectamente.
Cuando hago "login" en la web, usando "var_dump y die" veo cómo sí me crea el objeto y me redirecciona a mi base_url, pero no me saca el nombre del usuario (que tengo configurado en el html de mi aside para que salga así), y siguen apareciendo los inputs de "email y contraseña" que son con los que se logea en mi tienda.

¿Alguien sabe qué es?
Seguro que es una tontería, pero no lo veo :( .

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Aquí os pongo el código: (miProyecto/views/layout/sidebar.php)

```
<aside id="left">

    <div id="login" class=block_aside">
        
        <?php if(!isset($_SESSION['identity'])): ?>
         
            <h3>Entrar a tu cuenta</h3>
                        
        <form action="<?=base_url?>user/login" method="post">

            <label for="email">Email</label>

            <input type="email" name="email"</>

            <label for="password">Contraseña</label>

            <input type="password" name="password"</>

            <input type="submit" value="Enviar"</>

        </form>
        <?php else: ?>
            <h3><?=$_SESSION['identity']->name?></h3>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

luego en user.php (miProyecto/models/user.php)

```
public function login(){
        
        $result= false;
        $email= $this->email;
        $password= $this->password;
        
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'";
        $login = $this->db->query($sql);
        
        
        if($login && $login->num_rows == 1){
            
            $user = $login->fetch_object();
            
            $verify = password_verify($password, $user->password);
            
            if($verify){
                
                $result = $user;
            }
        }
                
        return $result;        
        
    }
```

Y luego en userController.php (miProyecto/controllers/userController.php)

```
public function login(){
        
        if(isset($_POST)){
            
            $user= new User();
            $user->setEmail($_POST['email']);
            $user->setPassword($_POST['password']);
            
            $identity = $user->login();
            
            
            if ($identity && is_object($identity)){
                    $_SESSION['identity'] = $identity;
                
                if($identity->rol == 'admin'){
                    $_SESSION['admin'] = true;
                }
                    
            }else {
                    $_SESSION['error_login'] = 'Ha fallado la identificación';
            }
            
          
        }
        header("Location:".base_url);
    }
```

Comment: Con lo que has compartido no podremos ayudarte. ¿Cuál es el código que gestiona el login y la redirección cuando éste es exitoso? Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta.

Comment: Acabo de editar el código para que me ayudéis a encontrar el problema, muchas gracias :)

Comment: Yo veo dos funciones `login()`  en dos archivos, pero, ¿en qué momento llamas a esas funciones? ¿desde qué código exactamente?